# How to remove withEndAction runnable when activity destroys view?

Tags: android, animation

How to remove withEndAction runnable when activity or fragment destroys view? I get NPE, because when user presses back button animation is executing, and then when runnable is called, all the views are null. Of course I can put null pointer if checks, but I maybe there is another better way.

```
view.animate().translationY(TRANSLATION_Y).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            otherview.setText(...);
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**view.animate()** is returning a [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) instance which is responsible for animations and which keeps your **animationEndRunnable**.

```
view.animate()
    .yBy(20)
    .setDuration(300)
    .withEndAction(animationEndRunnable)
    .start();
```

To cancel the Runnable that was passed via **.withEndAction()** call you can simply call **view.animate().cancel()** on the same view it was posted.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    view.animate().cancel();
}
```